# Git - Merge a part of branch commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

How could I merge several, selected commits from branch B into A. I did this but I am not sure if there is a one line solution for this:

```
git log -p -1 B~~ | git apply
git log -p -1 B~ | git apply
git commit -m 'Merge penultimate and before penultimate B commits into A'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use git [`cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)

In your case (when branch A is your current HEAD):

`git cherry-pick B~1`

Comment: In TortoiseGIT, switch to the branch you want to merge into (A), then select "Merge" and simply select the commit that you want to merge into your current branch.

Answer (score 2):

For applying selected commits use [`cherry-pick`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-cherry-pick).

---

**UPD**: totally agreed with @jmh comment. Merge commit as you know is just another usual commit but with many child commits. It is not like applying all commits from different branch.

So if you wanna apply some specific commits from different branch, cherry-pick will work here fine.

Comment: In particular a 'merge' of only some commits from branch B into branch A isn't really a 'merge' at all, since not all of the changes from the other branch have been incorporated.  A cherry-pick on the other hand is for pulling in specific commits.